# .svg not exported through org-export + paragraphs not separated after newline

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, linux

I have been constantly trying to render a `logo.svg` found in my custom title-page (included in `#LATEX:`) to match our university title-page for academic writings, but have unfortunately not had success doing so. I have since yesterday been trying to render the `.svg` files included in my `.org` writing, but unfortunately arrived at no solution..

*Note that the following list includes methods I have attempted in a doom-emacs enivronment to resolve the issue while having inkscape, libsvg and imagemagick installed on my system.*

What I have tried by far:

1. Used different formats (`.png`, `.pdf` and `.svg`), but failed to display any image through both `\includegraphics` and `\includesvg`. Keep arriving at: "cannot find file" and I do not know how to resolve this issue. I have tried to use both full/relative paths, but couldn't produce the desired output.
2. `.svg` files located inside `.org` files are not exported through org-export even after including `#+LATEX_HEADERS: \usepackage{svg}`. I suspect that this could be the issue, but I am not certain.
3. `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex` returns the same issue as org-export does, which is the `.svg` images not being displayed.

Another issue that I am facing is paragraphs not being created for lines separated by a newline between them. Because of this, my text currently looks like one mash of text without any separation, which is in my opinion looking hideous.

If you know how to resolve this issue, please do help me since dropping emacs because of this is in my personal opinion not a wise choice. Not to mention that I am really comfortable in my doom-emacs environment and would prefer it over writing my academic work in google-docs. :/

Comment: The pastebin for both the `template.tex`and the `file.org` can be found at: [custom title-page](https://pastebin.com/bPZGZhLN) and [org-file](https://pastebin.com/bA5tT724)

Comment: The paragraph issue was resolved through `#+OPTIONS: \n:t` thanks to Ryan from the org-mode matrix server. Will update if I figure out how to configure paragraphs to adjust them to `\begin{equation}`.

Comment: Removed `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`, replaced `includesvg{logo.svg}` with `\includesvg{src/logo.svg}`and also included `--shell-escape` in org-mode `config.el` to fix this issue thanks to hpd from org-mode matrix server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1. Paragraph spacing: add `#+OPTION: \n:t`.
2. Fix svg rendering issue: add --shell-escape to `config.el` (doom-emacs):

```
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

3. Source `logo.svg` in `file.org` based on the relative path of `logo.svg` from `file.org`. In my case the relative path is `src/logo.svg`, which results in: `\includesvg{src/logo.svg}`

Appreciate the help both @ryan_c_scott and @hpd from `org-mode` matrix server have provided me and wish that this will be useful to someone else facing the same issue!

Comment: You can 'accept' your own answer, which helps us by removing your question from the 'unanswered' queue.